# Alternative to SWARM FTP batch processing?

Tags: batch-file, batch

In a proposed project the plan is to divide large data sets into chunks, expose them by SFTP into a swarm CPU type of LAN cluster architecture for processing of historical numerical and financial data for simulations. Time consuming.

What about using something like Influxdb? I know about sharing and scaling a bit. Could we take advantage of this in how it distributes data to nodes and perform processing on them?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some other requirements? Multiple tools can achieve that, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_job_scheduler_software) is a list of some job schedulers which can distribute a workload *(some are open source)*

For instance:

- What is your infrastructure size?
- Do you have any security requirements?
- Do you have any need for tight integration with other solutions?
- etc.